# Ajax script doesn't work inside UIWebview

Tags: ajax, uiwebview

I was trying to implement the following situation.
A view with a UIWebview inside where it load a php file over the internet.Inside the php there is a button where executes a script.After execution,i want the page to refresh.
Here is my code:

PHP in webview

```
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="karate('<?php echo $id;?>')"/>
```

Ajax Scipt

```
function karate(el){
$.post("update.php", {"ida": el } )
.done(function() {
window.location.reload()

});
}
```

Desktop safari works,after execution the page reloads it self.Does UIwebview have some restrictions over reload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some strange,very strange reason worked after i edited the .done function

```
function karate(el){
$.post("update.php", {"ida": el } )
.done(function(data) {
document.location.reload(true);
});

}
```